Can Power Query or Power Piviot gives the Sub total of each section?
I have a table with multiple sections, each section has different queues. I have to subtotal at the end of the each section.
How Can I do it in Power Query or Power Pivot? I am not getting any idea to move on. Could anyone help me in this regard.
Thank you.
[

you can create pivot tables

then show subtotal at the bottom or top of each group

